# Fetching an API in react

Tags: reactjs, api

**I am new to React, And I am Stuck. I am trying to make a signup page, having textboxes: name,phonumber,email,password.**

**What I want is, When I click on login button, all these details should be sent over POST to my API, and response is fetched and stored.**

**API:**

```
http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup
```

**Method:**

```
POST
```

**Request to my api is send in this way:**

```
content-type: application/json

{ 

 "name": "Devanshh Shrivastvaaaa",
 "phoneNumber":"982964XXX8",
 "email": "devannnnnshh;@ccc.in",
 "password": "1234566788" 
}
```

**Can anyone please explain me using code how to send this data to my api on clicking signup, and fetching response**

Comment: This will help. It has examples as well
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need to use any third party libraries, just use the Javascript **fetch API**

```
// Example POST method implementation:
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

postData('https://example.com/answer', { answer: 42 })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `data.json()` call
  });
```

> [Source: Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 1):

you need to install axios or fetch axios is good   [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup', {
    name: "Devanshh Shrivastvaaaa",
     phoneNumber":"982964XXX8",
     email: "devannnnnshh;@ccc.in",
     password: "1234566788"
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

also check [for further](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-make-http-requests-like-a-pro-with-axios/)

Comment: I am new to react, can you please explain using code how to send headers, and how to fetch data after clicking on signup button.

Comment: I am new to react, can you please explain using code how to send headers, and how to fetch data after clicking on signup button.

Comment: in the response console you can get the data from server 
 `const options = {
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'value'}
};

axios.post('/save', { a: 10 }, options);`
refer the link i've mentioned you can find things